# Connecting two elements using a line/wire manually

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want the user to be able to connect a set of points using a wire or line. Connection is complete when points **1**, **2** and **6** are connected, otherwise if player makes wrong connections then screen shows wrong connections.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: i am a beginner but i can give you an flash example like which want to design mine. http://vem-iitg.vlabs.ac.in/Magnetic_Field_Behaviour_in_single_coil(experiment1).html    like this i also want to draw a line between two points.

Comment: For Javascript you have to use the (html5) canvas. look at: [lineTo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/canvas_lineto.asp).

Comment: Please be aware that we are not here to create and finish projects for you, we're here to help you solve issues with your existing code. If you want us to be able to help you, you'll need to show us what you've done in code.

Comment: PS: Don't tag `Flash` if you're not working with Adobe Flash or AS3 language. A "stack overflow" is a crash in code, so what's the problem in your own code?

Answer (score 0):

I can give some pointers to start with .

**Line Drawing**

On selection of node you can draw line and drop on other node . Keep capturing the node id and and if list has 1,2,6 say its correct or wrong

```
function drawLine(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

canvas.onmousedown = function (e)  {
    ctx.save();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}
canvas.onmousemove = function (e)  {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    drawLine(mouseX, mouseY);
}
canvas.onmouseup = function (e)  {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    isDown = false;
}
```